# Match session ID to a column with a string to get specific results based on logged user

Tags: php, mysql, session

for example $_session[eid]

```
select * from results where user = :eid
```

it should display results related only to the logged in user with reference to the use column
which has names as a string

Comment: *"for example `$_session[eid]`"* - I hope that that isn't the actual syntax you used, because it's incorrect. Your question is unclear for that reason and missing a lot of code.

Comment: What isn't working the way you'd like it to? You didn't post enough code or said what is wrong; I failed to see a question.

Comment: users table has columns id,fname and last name and results table has column id, user,details. So when a certain user logs in it should display his details alone not the whole table. user column combines fname and lname from user table

Answer (score -1):

If you want use like variable just start like:

```
session_start();
$eid=$_SESSION['eid'];
$query=$mysqli->prepare("select * from results where user = ?");
$query->bind_param('i',$eid);
execute ecc ecc......
```

Comment: *"where user = :eid"* - That is "PDO", not "mysqli_".

Comment: They also asked how to display but I feel their question is too unclear as posted.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner the question was how use session variable, then he must learn how to use that alone. i just do an example. why downvote?